# Canon LBP2900 and Debian Wheezy

Tags: printer, debian-wheezy

I use Canon LBP2900 and Debian Wheezy amd64.
I installed the official 64bit driver from Canon site (alien --scripts --to-deb *.rpm).

Add printer to 59687 socket:

```
lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59687 -E
```

captstatusui -P LBP2900
the window open with the messages:

```
Printer Error
Check the DevicePath of /etc/ccpd.conf
```

I have checked /etc/ccpd.conf and found an error.

```
> cat /etc/ccpd.conf

<Path>
CUPS_ConfigPath /etc/cups/
</Path>

<Printer LBP2900>
DevicePath /dev/usb/lp1
</Printer>

<Ports>
UI_Port 59787
PDATA_Port 59687
</Ports>
```

USB device:

```
> ls -la /dev/usb/lp1
crw-rw---T 1 root lp 180, 1 Ноя 28 15:25 /dev/usb/lp1
```

How to fix?

Comment: The official driver download contained Debian packages. Why did you not use them?

Comment: Official driver for i386. I use amd64.

Comment: Why didn't you use the 64-bit Debian packages, then?

Comment: Official driver for Debian (deb packages) i386 only (32 bit). I use 64 bit.

Comment: The official driver contains _both_ 32-bit and 64-bit packages for Debian. Look more closely. `Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN/64-bit_Driver/Debian/cndrvcups-capt_2.60-1_amd64.deb` and `Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN/64-bit_Driver/Debian/cndrvcups-common_2.60-1_amd64.deb` are plainly 64-bit Debian packages.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I installed the driver version 2.6 (64-bit Debian packages) but the problem remained.

Answer (score 0):

wrong:

```
lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59687 -E
```

correct:

```
lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp:localhost:59687 -E
```

No need for `//` after `ccp:`.